# Number Theory proving questions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Prove that

$x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod n$

is not solvable for integer $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be an integer of the form $4k+3$ then it's divisible by a prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$, otherwise all its divisor will be of the form $4k+1$ and it will be also of this form.

Let $p=4k+3$ such a prime , and assume that there is some integer $x$ such that $x^2\equiv -1 \mod n\equiv -1\mod p$ then we have $x^{p-1}\equiv (x^2)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv (-1)^{2k+1}\equiv -1 \mod p$

now using [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we have $x^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p$ which is absurd.

Comment: Doesn't F$\mathcal l$T apply to primes only?